# I'm having trouble with whitespace being colored in the GCP Cloud Shell Editor

Tags: javascript, editor, whitespace, google-cloud-shell

I was coding JavaScript in a cloud shell editor and suddenly the white space was colored and it was very hard to see. How can I get rid of the whitespace color?

[image]

Comment: Is there any setting you changed or any steps we can follow to reproduce the problem? If not please add your `settings.json` to the post, you can find them in `/home/{YOUR USER}/.theia/` there shouldn't be any PII but please check it before posting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appearance of the screenshot you shared is what you see when you are in Cloud Shell Editor and you do Ctrl + F and then find occurrences of the space character.

The point is, when I reproduced this, I closed the window where I typed the text to be highlighted, and the highlighting disappears.

However, if you click in Search (the magnifying glass icon), and you find occurrences of the space character, the spaces are also highlighted in the code you are editing. Then when you click on the magnifying glass icon again, you will have the same appearance as in the screenshot, keeping the spaces highlighted, and not being able to know clearly why this is happening.

Comment: Thanks to you, I solved the problem.
The reason was that the text box that appeared when I clicked on the magnifying glass icon had white space left in it.
After clearing the text box, the distracting color disappeared.